# $anchorScroll is working on second click, when I have called in other submit function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, location

I am still facing this issue. My issue little a bit different

I am calling my $anchorScroll function in other event. When form is being submitted. It is working on second click same as above. I have also tried earlier anwsered solution, but no luck :(

```
 $scope.scrollTo = function(element) {
    var old = $location.hash();
    $location.hash(element);
    $anchorScroll();
    $( 'html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    $location.hash(old);
};
```

And I am calling it in another function, which is submitting the form.

```
 $scope.saveProfile = function (profile) {
 $log.debug("now the profile is " + JSON.stringify(profile));
 dataFactory.persistChange("profiles",profile,$scope,postSuccessUpdate);
  $scope.scrollTo( "#error ");
}
```

And here is my anchor

```
 <div ng-class="statusDisplayClass" ng-show="messages" id="error">
       Here it will be displayed
      </div>
```

Please help me on this. Where I am lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change your `$scope.scrollTo( "#error ");` to `$location.hash('error');
$anchorScroll();`.

It should look like below:

```
 $scope.saveProfile = function (profile) {
   $log.debug("now the profile is " + JSON.stringify(profile));
     dataFactory.persistChange("profiles",profile,$scope,postSuccessUpdate);
      $location.hash('error');
      $anchorScroll();
 }
```

I am not sure if that's work because in my environment it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply @gracia.

Comment: In my scenerio I am calling this $scope.scrollTO('#error'), in another function, which triggered on form submission.
So, it is rendering saveProfile function first and rendering the whole DOM, where I am facing this issue. Moreover, I also have tried with $routeParams and other route plugins but no luck.

Comment: Does anybody have any further solution for my query ? Please help me on  this as I am new in angularjs :)

Comment: Have you tried to read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: Yes I have tried all these things. My scenerio is like this. I have a function called like 'saveProfile' which is getting response and throwing either error or successful message. I tried to call this msg, when it got response but still it is working on second click. I don't know what is happening here. I tried to stop propogation too but no luck. Thanks for your reply once again.I'll figure it out and let know here what was the problem.